# Require file in functions from theme directory using PHP

Tags: functions

I am trying to dynamically get the facebook php sdk from my current themes folder.

I am writing this in my functions.php, but all my attempts break the site.

See my attempts below...

```
require template_url('/') . 'facebook-php-sdk-6c82b3f/src/facebook.php';

require get_bloginfo('template_url') . 'facebook-php-sdk-6c82b3f/src/facebook.php';
```

Can any one help me understand why this does not work?

Thank you very much.

Comment: have you echoed the result of your statements and seen what you're asking to be required? Might be a good starting point.

Comment: I just realized that it works with out the template url part. I thought I might have to require the full path, but it works relative to the where the functions php is. Silly me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`get_template_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) instead , require doesn't work with http://

Comment: you're welcome, but like you said you don't need the full path.

Answer (score 0):

I did not actually need to use the full path, it works using a relative path from the functions.php

require 'facebook-php-sdk-6c82b3f/src/facebook.php';